# Equilibrium involving water and solid component

Tags: equilibrium, concentration, phase

$$\ce{A + B <=> C(s) + H2O(l)}$$

Why when $\ce{H2O}$ is liquid and $\ce{C}$ is solid, the equilibrium constant of the reaction is

$$K_\mathrm{eq} = \frac{1}{[\ce{A}][\ce{B}]} \quad ?$$

Comment: I remember this being described as a "convention", as if to acknowledge that the role if a solid component of an equilibrium is ill -  defined. Would appreciate hearing from others on the subject.